# What method should I use to convert words into features for Machine Learning applications?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, word2vec

I am planning on building a gender classifier. I know the two popular models are tf-idf and word2vec. 
While tf-idf focuses on the importance of a word in a document and similarity of documents, word2vec focuses more on the relationship between words and similarity between them.

However none of theme seem to be perfect for building vector features to be used for gender classification. Is there any other alternative vectorization model that might suit this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is another alternative to w2v: [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).

GloVe stands for *Global Vector Embeddings*. 
As someone who has used this technique before to good effect, I would recommend GloVe.

GloVe optimally trains neural word embeddings not just by looking at local windows but considering a much larger width (30+ size), thereby embedding a much deeper level of semantics to the embedding.

With glove, it is easy to model relationships such as: `X[man] - X[woman] = X[king] - X[queen]`, where these are all vectors.

[image]

Credits: GloVe GitHub page (linked below).

You can train your own GloVe embeddings, or you may use their retrained models available. Even for specific domains, the general models seem to work reasonably well, although you would get a lot more out of your models if you trained them yourself. Please look at the GitHub page for instructions on how to train your own models. It is very easy.

Additional reading:

- [GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf)
- [GloVe repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe)

Comment: One question. Does GloVe support Hindi? Does any of the pre-trained model contain Hindi data?

Comment: @Djokester If you're talking about hindi written in english, then I do believe it will support that. However, actual hindi script? Can't say. I've never tried it before. It's worth a shot. Also, to my knowledge, no pretrained models of hindi exist.

Comment: Is there a Python package for GloVe? I didn't come across a reliable one.

Comment: Here's [one](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python) but I wouldn't swear by anything besides the original.

Comment: Thanks! it should do the job hopefully!

Comment: Cool. All the best.